# Extracting text within div tag itself with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the number eg. "3762" from the div below with Beautifulsoup:

```
<div class="contentBox">
   <div class="pid-box-1" data-pid-imprintid="3762">
   </div>
   <div class="pid-box-2" data-pid-imprintid="5096">
   </div>
   <div class="pid-box-1" data-pid-imprintid="10944">
   </div>
</div>
```

The div comes from this website (a pharma medical database): [Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/imprints.php?color=12&sort=rel&maxrows=50).

I can not use "class" since that changes from div to div, more than just pid-box-1 and pid-box-2. I haven't had success using the "data-pid-imprintid" either.

This is what i have tried and i know that i cant write "data-pid-imprintid" the way i have done:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
divs = soup.find_all('div', 'data-pid-imprintid')

for div in divs:
    item = div.find('div')
    id = item.get('data-pid-imprintid')
    print (id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the value of data-pid-imprintid in every div with data-pid-imprintid

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
divs = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"data-pid-imprintid": True})

for div in divs:
    print(div.get('data-pid-imprintid'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First at all be aware there is a little typo in your `html` (class="pid-box-1'), without fixing it, you will only get two ids back.

#### How to select?

As alternativ approache to `find_all()` that works well, you can also go with the `css selector`:

```
soup.select('div [data-pid-imprintid]')
```

These will select every `<div>` with an `attribute` called `data-pid-imprintid`. To get the `value` of `data-pid-imprintid` you have to iterate the `result set` for example by `list comprehension`:

```
[e['data-pid-imprintid'] for e in soup.select('div [data-pid-imprintid]')]
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<div class="contentBox">
   <div class="pid-box-1" data-pid-imprintid="3762">
   </div>
   <div class="pid-box-2" data-pid-imprintid="5096">
   </div>
   <div class="pid-box-1" data-pid-imprintid="10944">
   </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

ids = [e['data-pid-imprintid'] for e in soup.select('div [data-pid-imprintid]')]

print(ids)
```

#### Output

```
['3762', '5096', '10944']
```